# Segmentation fault in c array, access to individual char in a string

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am attempting to manipulate individual characters in a string, in this case change 4th 'a' to a 'b'.

```
string password = "aaaaa";
printf("password: %s\n",password);

int j = 'b';
password[3] = (char) j;
printf("password: %s\n",password);
```

this returns:

password: aaaaa

Segmentation fault

One last note: in the first line I declare 'string' like a variable. This contrivance is allowed by the CS50 library - It should work and I have used it in the past.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I now updated the tag. Yes I am doing the excellent cs50 and have included #include <cs50.h>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"aaaaa";` is a *String Literal* which is immutable on most systems, so `password[3] = (char) j;` attempts of modify an immutable object resulting in a SegFault.

Instead,

```
char password[] = "aaaaa";
```

Presuming your `"string"` is a `typedef` of `char*` using a *compound literal* allows the same result, e.g.:

```
string password = (char[]){"aaaaa"};
```

Comment: That's done it, thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Good luck with your coding.